# What is window.usrc in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

What does `window.usrc` mean? What does it do? I've seen it [here](https://gist.github.com/peterbe/9117f2c9fc10d4c3ad274ecd61a36fb3), for example.

Answer (score 1):

`window.usrc` will get the value of `usrc` property of the `window` object. Thus, in the [gist](https://gist.github.com/peterbe/9117f2c9fc10d4c3ad274ecd61a36fb3) the code `window.usrc = document.location.href` assign a value to `window.usrc` which is accessed globally throughout the application. So, whenever you access `window.usrc` it will return you the value of `document.location.href`

```js
window.usrc = 'someValue';
console.log(window.usrc);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is just another way of defining the variable in the global (`window`) scope. It isn't any standard `window` object property. You can always check them *globals* here: [MDN Window WebAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window).

Answer (score 1):

In `window.usrc` `usrc` is simply a property of `window` object. In this case `usrc` property holds URL of the current page.